# How can I make a 100% width div have its children scroll horizontally when the parent is embedded in a display:table?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

My site has a sidebar on the left and main content on the right.  The layout structure is done with divs of `display:table`.  (I'm open to changing this as long as the effect is the same).

Now in the main content section, I want an area that is horizontally scrollable.  That area needs to be 100% of the main content width and NOT push it wider.  However, it's not working as intended and I can't figure out why it's pushing the content area wider.

Here is a mockup in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yhpjx907/1/

Uncomment some of the extra items and you'll see what I mean about it expanding the main content.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about setting `width` for your `.wrapper` ? Your `.container` is `500px`, your `.sidebar` is `150px` so let say `350px` for your `.wrapper` ?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I should have mentioned that my real container is responsive, so the width is not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **flexbox**:

Left side has the same height as right side. Left side `width: 30%`. Right side `width: 70%`. Right side inline elements are also in a flexbox, which has `overflow-x: scroll`.

#### Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container>aside {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 150px;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  color: #fff;
}

.container>.main {
  width: 70%;
  border: 5px solid #cfcfcf;
  background: #fff;
}

.container .items {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container .items>div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>List 1</li>
      <li>List 2</li>
      <li>List 3</li>
      <li>List 4</li>
      <li>List 5</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="items">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>13</div>
        <div>14</div>
        <div>15</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried this, but the key was to have the sidebar 30% and main content be 70%.  As soon as I added explicit percent widths on those flex items, everything worked.